# Using computer alias with https

Tags: asp.net, macos, iis, iis-express, parallels

I develop asp.net apps on a mac using parallels. I am trying to achieve that when I run a web, it opens in my Mac Chrome. There is a nice guide how to do that:

http://www.dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2015/08/25/browser-debugging-between-os-x-and-visual-studio-in-parallels/

I have followed the guide and it works with one annoying issue that I am trying to fix but haven't succeeded yet. When I open the solution and the web project loads or when I save the project settings I get the following warning:

[image: VS warning]

The error occurs when I modify bindings in a site element in **applicationhost.config** which can be found in `<solutiondir>\.vs\config\*applicationhost.config`:

**Modified site element/bindings**

```
<site name="UnitechSales" id="2">
    <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
        <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Projects\UnitechSalesApp\UnitechSales" />
    </application>
    <bindings>
        <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:51267:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
        <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:arrakis-win" />
    </bindings>
</site>
```

The original file simply does not contain the binding elements with the computer name and contains only localhost bindings.

When I run the website, it correctly opens in my mac browser. However, getting the error all the time is quite annoying.

---

### Edit

**.csproj IIS**

```
<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
<IISExpressSSLPort>44300</IISExpressSSLPort>
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
```

**.csproj Web project ext**

```
<WebProjectProperties>
    <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
    <AutoAssignPort>False</AutoAssignPort>
    <DevelopmentServerPort>51267</DevelopmentServerPort>
    <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
    <IISUrl>https://arrakis-win:44300</IISUrl>
    <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
    <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
    <CustomServerUrl>
    </CustomServerUrl>
    <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
</WebProjectProperties>
```

Comment: I've been trying to reproduce this error in all the variations I can think of, but it all works fine for me. I suggested trying Local IIS but deleted that comment when it didn't look like that would work for me. Is there any error logged with IIS anywhere that maybe can give us a hint?

Comment: I looked into the event viewer and the visual studio log. Sadly, no errors or warnings logged there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to keep your project file (.csproj/.vbproj) in sync with your config file.

More technical details can be found in my blog post,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/11/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think this is not the issue :-/ I have included the .csproj parts into the question.

Comment: @Santhos please try to remove unused bindings from config file, and then retry. I have also updated my blog to include more information on machine name related settings. I could not reproduce the exact error message you met, but the new words should be helpful.

Comment: I have already tried that with no luck. I believe the problem is with the https. At least this is not work blocking issue (however annoying it is). The strange thing is that according to your https section, we have bascially the same setup. The only difference now is that my machine name is in lower case and yours in upper case, but I believe that cannot matter.

Comment: @Santhos then can you try the SSL Diag in Jexus Manager? https://Jexus.lextudio.com I wrote this tool and hope it can help out.